# Ubuntu 20 server htop shows 100% CPU usage, why?

Tags: server, cpu, nginx

The title says it all, and I also asked the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67464225/digitalocean-server-cpu-100-without-app-running

Not sure which is the right place to ask this question.

Here's the full page screenshot of the htop results:
[image]

What can I do to start investigating the cause?

Atm, there's no app running or anything when I ran the `htop`, but I have tested running an app and it runs without issues close to 24h till it stops running and server stops responding.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/devices and cloud use  that can use *snap* packages only.  Please clarify which product you are using  (*year* only releases mean a different product since 2016)   By Ubuntu 20, do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?

Comment: Sorry, a bit misleading I guess. My vps (digitalocean) OS is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Oh my F god, I ran `pm2 save --force` to sync running processes and the CPU went back to normal. I guess there was an app stuck or something that ate all the CPU. The one-click installation had an example app running I guess. Damn, that was unexpected.

Comment: Please correct your question then, Ubuntu 20 does imply it's the *snap* only product Ubuntu Core 20 (and not *deb* based which use *year.month* format in releases).

Answer (score 0):

I ran `pm2 save --force` to sync running processes and the CPU went back to normal.

I guess there was an app stuck or something that ate all the CPU.

Comment: Didn't help 
Do you happen to have anythings else tried simultaneously or happen to find some more info regarding this issue? Thanks in advance!